# yield multiple request to a same parse function. what is the order of function running? Scrapy

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, scrapy

basically my program has the following structure.

```
def first_parse:
  for link in links: 
    yield Request(url = link, callback = second_parse)

def second_parse:
   # webDriver.get(url) and crawl data.
```

I am using selenium Webdriver to load the url from first_parse. for each page, the program need some time to load the page and do the work. But for some reasons, I always miss some of link from links. 
So I am suspecting when the yield operation send the Request to second_parse, but the second_parse still working on the previous request. so that the Request missed. am I correct?
if not, what happened when the yield sending the Request? 
for example, if there are 20 links, the first_parse will send 20 requests to the second_parse function. the second_parse will take 10 seconds for each request, so when the first request running on the second_parse, the others will be waiting on a queue? or just gone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reusing the same `webdriver` instance in the `second_parse()` method. I suspect this is what causing problems since the already instantiated webdriver navigates to a different page when not done with the current. You should instantiate and then close a `webdriver` in the `second_parse()` method:

```
def second_parse(self, response):
   webDriver = webdriver.Firefox()
   webDriver.get(url)

   # scrape

   webDriver.close()
```

This though may lead to up to 20 browsers active at the same time.

Comment: It works, but it does not seem running in parallel? could u give me some ideas?

Comment: @HuazheYin okay, do you mean you see only one browser at a time? Could you please share the complete code you have at the moment? Thanks.

Comment: @HuazheYin could you please create a gist here: https://gist.github.com/. I would need a complete spider I can run to reproduce your issue. Thanks!

Comment: you will see whats going on there. its weird..@alecxe

Comment: @HuazheYin I will take a look later. See if you can make a separate question out of it so that others may help you too. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot! i will set it up later! @alecxe